# Why I cannot format the partition with Ubuntu?

Tags: windows, lvm

I have a problam with formating my Ubuntu partition. I installed Ubuntu yesterday, after the succesful instalation i noticed that i have lost every data on my disk. Today I try to reinstall windows but i have no partition where i can reinstall it. I cannot format tha partition with Ubuntu and I dont know why... When i was installing ubuntu i choosed to install it on LVM or something like this, I think that this fact have caused my problems.

PS: Sorry for my bad english

Comment: What did you try? actually LVM is used when one wants to resize there partitions and create new one's from existing.so it will be much more easier to create a partition.just few commands is all you need.But first tell me what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

You have formatted you partition as ext4 while installing Ubuntu and Windows do not recognize ext4 format . So it is not showing when you try to install Windows.

Also you have single partition and your ubuntu is installed on that partition. So you can not resize that partition when Ubuntu is running.

Try to boot with ubuntu in live mode . In live mode open `Gparted` and resize your partition to create new partition  and format it as ntfs so that windows can recognize it.